# Importing a large .csv into Excel,

Tags: excel, csv, ado, large-files

I was trying to import a large .csv file into Excel. The file has close to 4 million rows and 329 columns so it far exceeded Excel's <strike>65536</strike> 1M row limit. I found a VB script online to import text files into Excel where once the row limit was exceeded the script would create a new worksheet till the total rows in all worksheets equal the total rows in the original text file.

```
Sub ImportLargeFile()
'Imports text file into Excel workbook using ADO.
'If the number of records exceeds 65536 then it splits it over more than one sheet.

Dim strFilePath As String, strFilename As String, strFullPath As String
Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim oConn As Object, oRS As Object, oFSObj As Object

'Get a text file name
strFullPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")

If strFullPath = "False" Then Exit Sub  'User pressed Cancel on the open file dialogue

'This gives us a full path name e.g. C:\temp\folder\file.txt
'We need to split this into path and file name
Set oFSObj = CreateObject("SCRIPTING.FILESYSTEMOBJECT")

strFilePath = oFSObj.GetFile(strFullPath).ParentFolder.Path
strFilename = oFSObj.GetFile(strFullPath).Name


'Open an ADO connection to the folder specified
Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
           "Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";" & _
           "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""

Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")

'Now actually open the text file and import into Excel
oRS.Open "SELECT * FROM " & strFilename, oConn, 3, 1, 1
While Not oRS.EOF
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset oRS, 65536
Wend

oRS.Close
oConn.Close

End Sub
```

However, when I run it in Excel 2007 I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':

Syntax error in FROM clause.
```

On clicking debug it points to this line

```
    oRS.Open "SELECT * FROM " & strFilename, oConn, 3, 1, 1
```

I have non-existent VB skills so any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: I found this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193514 but this doesn't work in this case, in fact, I am not even sure where to place the square brackets. Any place I put the brackets in that line, Excel refuses to give me the run option.

Edit 2: I tried running this on a different machine which just has a lot more juice in it to make memory not an issue. This computer also has Office 2013 on it (no Office 365 with it though). I ran the same macro on that and it gave the following error.

```
Run-time error '3706':
Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.
```

When I click Debug it points to this line

```
oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
       "Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";" & _
->     "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
```

Comment: I don't know about vba either, but that `SELECT` part is SQL, which I understand a bit more. Could you perhaps include the headers of your csv and where you got the vba script?

Comment: Are headers different from columns? Forgive me if I sound obtuse, but VB really is completely alien to me.

Comment: No no, that's perfectly fine to ask. By the headers, I mean the column names in your csv, if you have them. The MS support link you provided mentions that column headers/names in the file you're importing containing a dash cause this error. Conversely, you could import the file in MS access if you know how to use it a bit and export smaller pieces to excel. Before getting there though, I would like to see where you got this vba script, maybe there're some guidelines there.

Comment: Try adding `Debug.Print "SELECT * FROM " & strFilename` and see what you get in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G in the VB Editor).  does your filename have any spaces?

Comment: If it does have spaces then you need to enclose the filename in `[]` in your SQL. `oRS.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & strFilename & "]"`  http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/05/24/how-can-i-use-ado-to-open-a-text-file-that-has-spaces-in-the-file-name.aspx

Comment: @Jerry these are the headers

    `"NPI","Entity Type Code","Replacement NPI","Employer Identification Number (EIN)","Provider Organization Name (Legal Business Name)","Provider Last Name (Legal Name)","Provider First Name","Provider Middle Name","Provider Name Prefix Text","Provider Name Suffix Text","Provider Credential Text","Provider Other Organization Name","Provider Other Organization Name Type Code","Provider Other Last Name","Provider Other First Name","Provider Other Middle Name","Provider Other Name Prefix Text","Provider Other Name Suffix Text","Provider Other Credential Text"`

Comment: I tried importing it into Acess but I get a Bad File error or <Something else> error there. @TimWilliams I tried that and that stops the script as well. I am about to try debug.print.

Comment: @Jerry those aren't even half of them, but i kept running out of character limits

Comment: There are several Text Editor's / Csv Editor's that can handle files of this size, You could use one of them split the file up then import the different files into Excel. From memory Open Office spread sheet support > 4M rows.

Comment: maybe interesting? different approach - [How do you deal with large data sets in Excel?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-deal-with-large-data-sets-in-Excel)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into PowerPivot?  It is a free add-in from Microsoft.  It will allow you to connect to the original data source, or use your entire CSV, and load millions of rows (beyond the cell limits).  You can summarize the data in Pivot Tables, apply functions to the data, etc.  PowerPivot was tailor-made for situations like yours.

[Download](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/download-powerpivot-HA101959985.aspx)

Comment: PowerPivot looks promising, what sucks though is that it needs office 365 to install for Office 2013, which is what I just upgraded to on the machine that has more juice in it.

Comment: LOL, 7 years after writing this answer, it received its first upvote. Thank you who ever you are!

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2007 has no 65K limit, as far as I know. Just try importing the csv directly.

EDIT: Comments tell it has a 1M limit, so there is need in splitting the file. When it is simple (no quoted text with linebreaks), then split and head would help. They are availiable under Windows too.

Comment: According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730921.aspx#Office2007excelPerf_Overview Excel 2007's limit is 1 million rows which is still less than what this file has. The file being imported has no '-' in it's name does have one space though

Also, I did try opening it in Excel - in fact that was the first thing I did. Didn't work.

Comment: Excel 2007's actual limit is about 1M now. It's 65536 in Excel 2003.

Comment: i would prefer not to split it and keep it in one workbook with multiple sheets, which is why the script comes into picture.